# Docker is not updating the database schema when i use bind mounts as volumes to store database data even when the container destroyed

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

Initially i have created a test mysql image with **mysql 8** as base image and placed the **.sql** file inside the entrypoint **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/** of the image.

After successfully building the image. executed a container of that image using the below command

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysql_test_container_old --net=host -v /home/user/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql_test_image:v1.0
```

In this container there are two tables, external application will access the database and inserts some data.

I stopped the container using below command

```
   docker stop mysql_test_container
```

Updated the schema in the **mysql_test_image** by adding one more table in the schema and built with a new tag **v1.1** as **mysql_test_image:v1.1**

In this case i want to restore the data for the last two tables by using the volume and want to create new table with which i have updated the schema in the new tag.
I am trying to achieve this by using the below command

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysql_test_container_new --net=host -v /home/user/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql_test_image:v1.1
```

But the **mysql_test_container_new** is not executing the new .sql file which has three tables rather than it is just copying the old properties from the volume.

so when i go and look into the **mysql_test_container_new**, i am able to see only the two old tables with data and the new table which was mentioned in the schema of the newly tagged image is not created.

i am not sure that this can possible or i should know that am i trying it in a wrong way ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look to see if there's a _database migration_ tool for your application framework.  That will be designed to do tasks like add new tables to an existing database, and it won't be Docker-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run on database *initialization*, i.e. when there is no database when you start the container.

So they're run when you run the container for the first time. But on the second run, there's already a database there, so no initialization is done.

If you need to modify the database, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, is there any way that i want to modify the database and wants to restore the old data at once

Comment: Based on the change you want to make, how to do it may vary. Maybe you need to create a new table or ALTER an existing one. Maybe you need to save the data, modify the table and load it again. It's hard to make a process that works for all migrations.